Self signed certificate error in ASP.NET Core and Angular SSR application
I am developing ASP.NET Core and Angular SSR application.
I get error message: "Http failure response for https://127.0.0.1:44301/api/settings: 0 undefined, cause: Error: self-signed certificate", when I send API request.
My launch script is:
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "run-script-os",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "prestart": "node aspnetcore-https",
    "start:windows": "ng serve --ssl --ssl-cert \"%APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\%npm_package_name%.pem\" --ssl-key \"%APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\%npm_package_name%.key\" --host=127.0.0.1",
    "start:default": "ng serve --ssl --ssl-cert \"$HOME/.aspnet/https/${npm_package_name}.pem\" --ssl-key \"$HOME/.aspnet/https/${npm_package_name}.key\" --host=127.0.0.1"
}

My angular.json settings file:
"serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
    "configurations": {
        "production": {
            "buildTarget": "aspnetcoreangular.client:build:production"
        },
        "development": {
            "buildTarget": "aspnetcoreangular.client:build:development",
            "port": 44301,
            "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.js",
            "ssl": true
        }
    },
    "defaultConfiguration": "development"
}

It works with browser side rendering, but not with SSR.

I guess you can try this in your server code
